# SkSpritenode normal texture not restoring even with restore on?

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, sktexture

Ok. I am having a very odd problem with SKTextures and animating through - I have created a sprite node like this and set the normal texture to the last image in the array of sktextures I will eventually animate through. The texture (not normal texture) is set to the first image in the array.

```
theSprite = SKSpriteNode()
        theSprite.texture = atlas[0]
        theSprite.normalTexture = atlas[atlas.count-1]
        theSprite.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 1491)
        theSprite.position = CGPoint(x: basePos.x+1, y: basePos.y+2)
        superScene.addChild(theSprite)
```

when clicked it runs this func and as I read here https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417810-animate I have restore set to TRUE so it SHOULD end on the last frame of the array:

```
 let anim = SKAction.animate(with: atlas, timePerFrame: animSpeed, resize: false, restore: true)
            theSprite.run(anim, completion: {() -> Void in

            })
```

It should go back to normal texture (which is a blank image), but it doesn't. The only way it goes back to this is if I don't set the texture to begin with, which I need to do. How can I make it restore?

Comment: skyguy, I posted an answer. let me know if I need to clarify anything. On a side note, what are you trying to do with the normalTexture?

Comment: skyguy, I think you need to clarify exactly how many textures there are and what order you want them animated in. This will not only clarify your question, but will help you get better answers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggested Solutions**

Try setting your sprite to the last texture in the atlas like this: `theSprite.texture = atlas[atlas.count-1]`. Then run your code again. You should see that it restores to back to `atlas[atlas.count-1]`.

If your animation stops at a texture other than your last atlas texture, then you could try this. Set `theSprite.texture = atlas[atlas.count-1]` within your animation's completion block. You would also set `restore` to `false` in this case. This will animate your sprite then set the final texture to whatever you want, in this case it will be set to the last atlas texture.

**Explanation**

Restore will return your sprite back to the texture that it had before the animation began. So in your case with your current code, it should end the animation with the texture `atlas[0]`. It is not meant to end on the last frame of the array as you stated.

According to the Apple dev reference, if `restore` is `true`:

> When the action completes, the sprite’s texture is restored to the
>   texture it had before the action completed. 
>   https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417810-animate

Comment: But what if I need to have it start off (before animation is triggered) at the first texture in the atlas? Mweaning I need the animated to "transform" its texture

Comment: In my answer I stated you can try to restore the sprite to the last texture in the array with `theSprite.texture = atlas[atlas.count-1]` within your animation's completion block. This way you can keep the first texture with atlas[0].

Comment: So with restore still true, first when creating the sprite set it to atlas[0].  then atlas[atlas.count-1] in completion block? May have tried that but Ill experiment again

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that restore should be off for your case. Remember that restore will set the sprite's texture back to the texture it had **before** the animation began.

Comment: Never mind - problem with getting the images in order to begin with. Thanks for helping out

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)